# Sorting over a sum from two tables in mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I can't figure out a query that will add and compare across tables.  I have three tables:

house

```
id
-----
 1
 2
```

month

```
id | house_id | btus
---------------------
 3 |   1      | 100
 4 |   2      | 200
```

car

```
id | month_id |  btu
--------------------------
 5 |   3      |  10
 6 |   4      |  20
 7 |   3      |  15
```

I need a query that will return the house ids sorted by total btus for the month and car.

So for the above example it would return 2,1 as (200+20) > (100 + 10 + 15)

Comment: Should it rather be `(100 + 10 + 15)`?

Comment: Yes...it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  h.*
FROM    house
ORDER BY
        (
        SELECT  SUM(c.btu)
        FROM    month m
        JOIN    cars c
        ON      c.month_id = m.id
        WHERE   m.house_id = h.id
        ) +
        (
        SELECT  SUM(m.btus)
        FROM    month m
        WHERE   m.house_id = h.id
        )
        DESC
```

, or this one (probably slightly more efficient):

```
SELECT  h.*
FROM    house
ORDER BY
        (
        SELECT  SUM
                (
                btus +
                (
                SELECT  SUM(btu)
                FROM    cars c
                WHERE   c.month_id = m.id
                )
                )
        FROM    month m
        WHERE   m.house_id = h.id
        )
        DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most performant use of joins, but:

```
  SELECT house.id 
    FROM house JOIN month JOIN car
   WHERE house.id = month.house_id AND month.id = car.month_id
GROUP BY house.id
ORDER BY sum(car.btu) + sum(month.btus);
```

The joins and where clause will explode the tables (try it with SELECT * and skipping the group/order clauses), group by will flatten them to one row each, and the sum()s will do the relevant math.